# \n missing from f-string when written to file (Python 3.6.3)

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to print data in a for loop, but the output is omitting the '\n' at the end of the line ....

```
f.write(f'[{str(train_time[i])}] № {str(train_number[i])} {str(train_direct[i])}\n')
```

Why am I not getting a newline at the end? Putting '\n' at the end isn't doing that.

Here is the all block of code

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = str(f.read())
    train_time = re.findall(r'\d{3}\s\w+\s\w{1,2}.+(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2})', text)
    train_number = re.findall(r'(\d{3})\s\w+\s\w{1,2}.+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}', text)
    train_direct = re.findall(r'\d{3}\s\w+\s(\w{1,2}\s\w+)', text)

with open('output.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as f:
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(train_number)):
        f.write(f'[{str(train_time[i])}] № {str(train_number[i])} {str(train_direct[i])}\n')
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, try changing `newline='\n'` to `newline='\r\n'` (or, you know, don't mess with it and leave it at the default value...)

Comment: Thanks, That was exactly what I need.  Is this happens only on Windows?

Comment: No, the file is always the same regardless of your operating system. It's just that most programs on Windows use `\r\n` as line breaks, so when you use `\n` they display everything in the same line.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to format the strings in the end, you have to do it like in [here](https://pyformat.info/).

Also, after the format, try to add `'\n'` like this:

```
f.write(f'[{str(train_time[i])}] № {str(train_number[i])} {str(train_direct[i])}'+'\n')
```

Comment: The only change you made was to take the `\n` out of the string, which serves no purpose whatsoever except making the code more verbose and slower.

Comment: It's still the same.